# Get data from different table based on Id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a small e-commerce website and I want to display the reviews, and I want to create screen names for people (first letter of first name concatenated onto the last name), but I can't figure out how to get the information from my clients table. Let me show you the code I've done so far:

```
$invId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'invId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // this is taken from a name value pair from the view
// Gets the raw data from the database    
function getProRev($invId){
        $db = acmeConnect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE invId = :invId ORDER BY reviewId DESC";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':invId', $invId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $tn = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return $tn;
    }

// Builds the simple review display
function buildReviewDisplay($reviews){
    $rd = "<div id='reviewView'>";
    foreach ($reviews as $review){
        $rd .= "<h2>$review[clientId]</h2>";
        $rd .= "<h3>$review[reviewDate]</h3>";
        $rd .= "<p>$review[reviewText]</p>";
        $rd .= "<hr>";
    }
    $rd .= "</div>";
    return $rd;
}
```

As you can see, I'm displaying the clientId (a number) which is not what I want, and now this is where I'm stuck. I have the relationship between the two tables (clients and reviews) set up, but I can't figure out how to get the data. Here is the function I tried to write, but it didn't work:

```
// Trying to get the dang client info
function getUsername($clientId){
$db = acmeConnect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE clientId = :clientId";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':clientId', $clientId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$cd = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
$fletter = substr($cd['clientFirstname'], 0, 1);
$scrnam = $fletter . $cd['clientLastname'];
return $scrnam;
}
```

And I understand that this didn't work because there was nothing passing the `$clientId` parameter to the function, but the is contained in the `$tn[]` array, so there has to be a way that I can take the `$clientId` from the `$tn[]` array and query the database for the first and last name, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Can't you do `getUsername($review['clientId'])`?

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and PHP didn't like the [] inside of the function parenthesis

Comment: There's no problem with array accesses in function arguments, it's done all the time. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: Odd. Because declared exactly that and I got a terminating error that stated "unexpected '['". I'll have to look more into what I did.

Comment: You probably had an unmatched parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you wrote something like `getUsername[` instead of `getUsername(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the clients table to the reviews table in your first query.

```
SELECT * FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN clients ON reviews.clientId = clients.clientId
WHERE invId = :invId ORDER BY reviewId DESC
```

Then you'll have access to the client name columns without needing to execute an additional query for each review you display.

That way you can use your code from `getUsername` in `buildReviewDisplay`.

```
foreach ($reviews as $review) {
    $fletter = substr($review['clientFirstname'], 0, 1);
    $scrnam = $fletter . $review['clientLastname'];
    $rd .= "<h2>$scrnam</h2>";
    $rd .= "<h3>$review[reviewDate]</h3>";
    $rd .= "<p>$review[reviewText]</p>";
    $rd .= "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly!! Thank you! I guess I'm a little fuzzy on joins, so I need to go review those right now! Especially when to do a left vs a right join!

Comment: You're welcome. Left or right indicates the "owning" side of the relationship. In this case I used a left join so that all the reviews would be displayed even if there were any that had no matching client for some reason.